# Play an embedded youtube video in loop

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

Does anyone know how to make an embedded youtube video to play in loop?

I have tried the code generated from [official youtube developer website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) but it does not work at all. It doesn't replay after the video ends in both Firefox and Chrome. Here is the generated code that doesn't work.

```
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px">
    <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&feature=player_embedded&loop=1">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&feature=player_embedded&loop=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="425" height="344">
</object>
```

I have tried to google it but there aren't any good instruction.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try taking a look here https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop

Taken from the link

**Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter.** To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL:

`http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&loop=1&playlist=VIDEO_ID`

It appears that you may be missing the playlist parameter needed in conjunction with the loop paramenter.

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/E3Euv/

Comment: Thank you, it works but i got 2 videos of the same video in the playlist and so the video is reloaded every time it is replayed which is a waste of bandwidth. Is there any way to prevent that by not using playlist?

Comment: As stated by the reference document I don't believe so, but I'll try looking into it a bit more to help =)

Comment: Not a problem at all, I'm always glad to do what I can. I'm not seeing a way to do this without the playlist parameter currently, but if I find anything I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you. I could not find anything either. I am accepting your answer but if you have found anything please let me know.

Comment: I definitely will and if you find the answer please post it here and I'll update the answer for any future viewers. Thanks!

Comment: This may be a long shot, but it may be possible... If you can create a playlist with one video and use the parameters `list` and `listType` to link to that playlist ID. Like I said...may not work, but could be worth trying if you have a chance...sorry I couldn't help more, but I'm not seeing a better way to do it.

Comment: THANKS! Saved a day :)

Comment: The playlist param was my problem... when I set that, it works

Answer (score 4):

I can not leave a comment for Chase's accepted answer, but to have the Playlist show only ONE video and not two, just use the comma which separates video id's and allows **Playlist of 1** to be realized.

Example:
**&playlist=,**

jsfiddle update:
http://jsfiddle.net/E3Euv/1/

Comment: Although, the video is stilled re-downloaded, that's a nice trick. I gave you a vote up. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I've [posted](https://developers.google.com/youtube/forum/discussion?place=topic%2Fyoutube-api-gdata%2FT61ul91GeQU%2Fdiscussion) this as a bug to the YouTube Dev Forum since indeed the cache should be used.

Comment: It seems to be using cache if I have only one video in the playlist now. I haven't tested it for multiple videos but this is good enough for me. Thank you very much. I would have accepted this answer if it was the first.

Comment: But it still flashes black for a while before restarting the movie. This is ugly.

Comment: @SasQ, the jsFiddle demo uses a video that has 2 seconds of black, but the video that is replayed is not from cache which means any loading times (for slow connections) will need to be repeated again until the reported bug is addressed (but at this point, it appears YouTube will not address this issue). Watch this 11 second video twice and notice on the third replay there is zero black screens. [jsFiddle 11secs](http://jsfiddle.net/E3Euv/4/) Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure why, maybe because the jsfiddle is Flash but this solution doesn't work with an iframe player

Answer (score 1):

I have exhausted the possibilities with Youtube. If nothing else it's a bandwidth sucker as the video is reloaded each time.

I've uploaded my looping video to Vimeo. Problem solved.